# How to model EU Carbon Permits (EUR)?

Tags: regression, time-series, predictive-models, modeling

I'm trying to model EU Carbon Permits (EUR) using monthly data($P_t$) as shown below.

My objective is to predict EU Carbon Permits price from now to next 20 years (240 months) using monthly data. i.e. data from "after 1 month" to "after 240 month".

Since, there are some drift and volatility, I first consider using Geometric Brownian Motion(GBM).

So, I compute $\ln{\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}}$ and draw a qqplot and concludes that it is reasonable to think $\ln{\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}}$ follows normal distribution and GBM would be appropriate.

But then, I also think that predicting future 20 years (240 months) price would be almost impossible because variance would accumulate such that the result would be really high.

So, my question is, is it okay to use GBM in my case? Or, is it better to use other model?

If I should use another model, which model would be appropriate?

[image]

Comment: Instead of using a GBM, I suggest you try some discrete methods. For instance, using GARCH models for the returns, or ARMA models for the price. You could try using lagged variables with high correlation with the series of interest in order to forecast for the long term, similar to the idea of nowcasting. If you know R, I highly suggest using the machinery of *modeltime* package (see [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeltime/vignettes/getting-started-with-modeltime.html)), which I believe offers a wide toolbox for time series analysis.

Comment: @JesúsA. Thank you for giving me advices. I'll try it!